# Choosing a set of $m$ cards such that they all have distinct values

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coloring

A deck of $m*n$ cards with $m$ values and $n$ colors is made of one card of each value and color. The cards are arranged in any array with $n$ rows and $m$ columns. Show that we can pick a set of $m$ cards (one card from each column) such that they all have distinct values.

I cannot find the correct approach how to start such a task. I was thinking about Hall's theorem, but I think that it is not about it. My next thought was about using Vizing's theorem, but still can't get any idea how to start it. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: This is about Hall's marriage theorem.

Comment: So it is about showing that for every subset $S$ of $X$ we have inequality $|N(S)| \geq |S|$ satisfied, right? If so, then still I don't really have any idea how to start it.

Answer (score 0):

You want matching from columns to values, so that each column is matched to a value which appears in that column, and any two columns are matched to distinct columns. This is exactly the setup for Hall's marriage theorem; the columns are women, the values are men, and a woman is willing to marry a man if that value appears in that column. You just need verify Hall's condition that for collection $S$ of columns, the number of values appearing in these columns is at least $|S|$.

Note there are $n|S|$ cards total in these columns. If there were fewer than $|S|$ different values appearing in these columns, where each value has at most $n$ cards, then there would be fewer than $n|S|$ cards in these columns. This is a contradiction.